# Is this a bed bug? I found it crawling on me in hotel bed

Tags: species-identification

Is this a bed bag? It doesn't have the stripes that I saw in other pictures. I'm traveling and for 5 days I was sleeping in different hotel rooms. What should I do if it is. I searched the bed and found no more. [image]
[image]

Comment: Nope - it's a tick! If you can get a better photo I can tell you what species - dorsal and ventral surfaces, ideally.

Comment: Although probably an Ixodes, I suspect.

Comment: Since it's a tick, I would search on your skin, not in the bed. (Meaning: my first priority would be to make sure none of those beasts were attached to my body).

Comment: You should check that you haven't been bitten as some (not all) are know to carry Lime disease (http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Lyme-disease/Pages/Introduction.aspx)

Comment: Ticks and mites are allied to spider, which is an arachnid. Whereas bugs are a sort of insect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stated in the comments the animal you found is a [tick (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick).

Since they are known to carry diseases you should make sure you have not been bitten or even still have one sucking your blood. So search your body. If you happen to find one still attached, do NOT squeeze it as this may stimulate fluids to flow from the tick into your body (bad). Instead [get it out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick#Removal) asap using tweezers or even better specialized tools. If you can't do it yourself ask another person preferably a doctor.

If you have been bitten watch for symtoms of an infection such as a red circle. If in doubt always see a doctor since you might require antibiotic treatment.

**NOTE:** usually nothing happens so don't worry too much but be alert for changes in skin around bites (if bitten that is).

**EDIT:** since hotel beds are not a typycal habitat of ticks you probably carried it there yourself.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that hotel rooms are not their typical habitat. It's likely that the tick was transferred to the bed from OP's clothes.

Comment: Btw., the most dangerous infection would be [tick-borne encephalitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick-borne_encephalitis) which unlike [Lyme disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease) can't be treated. So, prevention (i.e., apart from vaccination, early removal of the tick) is important.

Comment: Ticks need humidity to survive, they often just climb onto a leaf or some grass when it's 17-23C degrees and jump on animals passing by. An interesting biological fact is that young ticks that have had a lizard host absorb the lizards lyme antibodies and have far less lyme desease later when they bite a bigger animal.